# How to hide playing track name in media player

Tags: html

I need to hide the track name that is getting played inside media player for Internet Explorer. Below is my code.

```
<object id="mediaPlayer" width="320" height="240" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject" name="mediaPlayer">
   <param name="URL" value="bcr_ahlacc.mpg" />
   <param name="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" value="true" />
   <param name="AutoStart" value="true" />
   <param name="PlayCount" value="1" />
   <param name="stretchtofit" value="true" />
   <param name="showstatusbar" value="true" />
   <param name="enablepositioncontrols" value="false" />
   <param name="showpositioncontrols" value="false" />
   <param name="enabletracker" value="false" />
   <param name="showcontrols" value="false" />
   <param name="showaudiocontrols" value="false" />
   <param name="enablecontextmenu" value="true" />
   <param name="uiMode" value="Full" />
```

it shows video name "bcr_ahlacc.mpg" while it is getting played, which I want to hide.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you need this:

```
<param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
```

> When set to `true`, it displays information such as the file name.

Info found [here](http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/windows-media/streaming/embed.html)

Comment: I need for classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" solution you shown is for older version of media player